# Триггер в MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Создаю триггер

```
CREATE TRIGGER InsertInOrderProducts
ON OrderProducts FOR INSERT
AS

BEGIN
    IF ((SELECT inserted.quantity FROM inserted) > (SELECT Products.balance FROM Products WHERE Products.id = inserted.product_id))
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRAN
        PRINT 'Нет требуемого колличества товара'
    END
END
```

Ошибка

> Не удалось привязать составной идентификатор "inserted.product_id".
>   Что делаю не так?

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TRIGGER InsertInOrderProducts
ON OrderProducts FOR INSERT
AS

BEGIN
    IF ((SELECT inserted.quantity FROM inserted) > (SELECT Products.balance FROM Products, inserted WHERE Products.id = inserted.product_id))
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRAN
        PRINT 'Нет требуемого колличества товара'
    END
END
```